# iphone uimapview to zoom to level of accuracy

Tags: iphone, mapkit, cllocationmanager

just a quick one - i can get the location of the user, i can set the zoom level - but how do i go about setting the zoom level to be respective of the accuracy.

So i would be zoomed quite far out if accuracy is poor, and zoomed quite far in if accuracy is good.

Bound to be simple, im just overlooking something here.

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CLLocationManager's `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method, you can use the `horizontalAccuracy` property in the `newLocation` parameter and create a region from it using the `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` function:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
                                (newLocation.coordinate, 
                                 newLocation.horizontalAccuracy, 
                                 newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);
```

The horizontalAccuracy is being passed for both the latitude and longitude spans.

Answer (score 0):

@burrows111 You can set the region to show to the user with
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userLocation;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = yourDistanceFilter;
    span.longitudeDelta = yourDistanceFilter;
    region.span = span;

Then, the current location will be centered in a region that u determinate in your "yourDistanceFilter", so this value could be different depending of the accuracy.

Comment: @burrows111 sorry by the format, but dun know why this thing is not formating.